# Benchmark battery life of laptop

Tags: windows, battery, battery-life

I am considering to sell my current laptop but never really used it for mobile purposes being disconnected for too long from a power supply. I want to test the durability of the battery of my laptop and would like to know which benchmark software you would suggest to find out how long a full battery charge will last in usual scenarios.

Comment: It's called a wristwatch.  You charge the battery, then run on battery doing what you usually do until the battery is low.  Then you look at your watch and see how long it lasted.  It isn't clear what you're looking for that's more complicated than that.

Answer (score 1):

- Disconnected AC and exercise the battery 100~50% a few times and 100%~2% at least once. No software is a mindreader.  LCD backlight is a major power use.

1)

- run cmd as admin >powercfg /batteryreport /output "C:\battery_report.html" {or any path and file name.html}
- http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7638/use-powercfg-in-windows-7-to-evaluate-power-efficiency/

2) through careful engineering, computers can achieve equal or improved performance over a clean Windows installation.  Unfortunately most users don't know how to make their MS "lite & efficient", so much energy is wasted. I call it lean and mean. Add a startup monitor app. That's all I've used for over 10yrs with occasional checks, like ADWcleaner.exe. ( I use Mike Lin's old startup monitor and Winpatrol)

3) even if you never go off AC your battery ages from heat and you lose Ah capacity.  So keep it cool with good ventilation and note 2) !